# Multiple Functions and Plots in Manipulate with multiple parameters

Tags: plotting, manipulate, column

```
prod[k_, a_] := a*k^0.5;
depr[k_, d_] := d*k;
Manipulate[
 Column[{
   Plot[prod[k, a], {k, 0, 10}, PlotRange -> {0, 10}],
   Plot[prod[k, a]/k, {k, 0, 10}, PlotRange -> {0, 10}]}],
 {a, 1, 5}]
```

[image]

How do you add the function $depr[k,a]$ in the upper graph? And in the lower graph $depr[k,a]/k$? $d$ should appear with controls to manipulate the value.

I also want to add a function which is a fraction of the $prod[k,a]$-function as $s*prod[k,a]$ with $0<s<1$ in the upper and $s*prod[k,a]/k$ in the lower graph.
$s$ should appear with controls to manipulate the value aswell.

Comment: Just list your desired plots in `Plot`, e.g.: `Manipulate[
 Column[{Plot[{prod[k, a], depr[k, a], s prod[k, a]}, {k, 0, 10}, 
    PlotRange -> {0, 10}], 
   Plot[{prod[k, a]/k, depr[k, a]/k, s prod[k, a]/k}, {k, 0, 10}, 
    PlotRange -> {0, 10}]}], {a, 1, 5}, {s, 0, 1}]`

Answer (score 2):

If I understand you correctly; you don't necessarily want `a` and `s` to take the same values in each of the plots. I'm not a big `Manipluate` user, so there may well be a better way, but the following should get you pretty close:

```
Column[{Manipulate[
   Plot[{prod[k, a], depr[k, a], s prod[k, a]}, {k, 0, 10}, 
    PlotRange -> {0, 10}], {a, 1, 5}, {s, 0, 1}], 
  Manipulate[
   Plot[{prod[k, a]/k, depr[k, a]/k, s prod[k, a]/k}, {k, 0, 10}, 
    PlotRange -> {0, 10}], {a, 1, 5}, {s, 0, 1}]}]
```

Basically, make the `Manipulate`s and put them in a `Column` rather than trying to `Manipulate` a `Column` of plots.

[image]